# Calculated column which includes foreign property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a `OrderBookItem` model.
I need to add column `TotalPrice`. This column calculates by formula `TotalPrice = Book.Price * Quantity`. I don't know how to do this properly. Need your help.

```
public class OrderBookItem
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("BookId")]
    public Book Book { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
    // need to calculate this property by formula `Book.Price * Quantity`
}
```

```
public class OrderBookItemDTO
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

As far as I understand, when passing `BookId` to DTO model and then mapping it, EF Core should automatically establish a connection between `BookId` and `Book`. Please correct me if I'm wrong

I tried many variants. But nothing helped me

Comment: Just store the book's price (at the moment of ordering) in `OrderBookItem`. Calculate `TotalPrice` real-time. Don't store it.

Comment: Hi @Andrey341,Entity Framework Core does not directly support the automatic calculation and storage of calculated fields in the database based on the properties of related entities due to the way it handles entity tracking and database updates.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I understand, when passing BookId to DTO model and then mapping it, EF Core should automatically establish a connection between BookId and Book.

It should map to a `Book` object but not the DTO object. So yes, it should reference an instance of `Book`, not necessarily an instance of a DTO class.

For calculating the price, the getters and setters should work for this.

In the `TotalPrice` property, it should be able to use the getter and setter to calculate that value. Add a private field that can store the value and return said value. Call it `totalPrice`.

```
private decimal totalPrice;

public decimal TotalPrice
{
    get { return totalPrice; }
    set { totalPrice = Book.Price * Quantity; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in Db this column contains the value '0' . Can you help with that?

Comment: Yeah, because `totalPrice` is never set. `TotalPrice` should be a get-only property without a backing field.

Comment: @GertArnold can you please help me, how to do this properly? My modest experience does not yet allow me to understand what you mean

Comment: Something like `public decimal TotalPrice => Book.Price * Quantity;` But this is typically something you don't want to store in the database. Just calculate it real-time when the value is needed. Anyway, the code in this answer doesn't make much sense.

Comment: It seems to me,like calculating real-time is not the best approach. The logic is quite primitive: 
Book + User -> Order. But user can order multiple books -> creating `OrderBookItem` and adding `ICollection<OrderBookItem> OrderBookItems` to `Order`
`OrderBookItem` stores `TotalPrice` value (`Book.Price *  Quantity`)
`Order` also stores `TotalPrice` column (calculates by`OrderBookItems.Sum(x => x.TotalPrice)`)

And if we change any data, we also need to recalculate this `TotalPrice` columns, but I'm convinced that we could wrote a logic that would calculate and recalculate it automatically

Comment: So you want a total price of a given `Book`, which is based on `Price` and `Quantity`. Should `TotalPrice` be stored in the database or not? If not, then the DTO object could just have something like what is stated in the comments, `TotalPrice => book.Price * Quantity;`. Then each item in the DTO object could have its own calculated price without having the `TotalPrice` on the order table.